# Want to increase the column-width in 2-column system using elsarticle

Tags: elsarticle

I want to increase the column width of my document, and it is a two-column document generated from the elsarticle. Using the following class and packages.

```
\documentclass[preprint,3p,twocolumn,times]{elsarticle}
%\documentclass[3p,times]{elsarticle}

%\usepackage{ecrc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage[caption]{subfig}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{picins}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{multicol}
```

how can we do this?

Comment: Why do you load both the `graphics` and the `graphicx` package?

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to create a preprint for an article to be submitted to an Elsevier journal (as per your preprint option in the declaration of document class), then you shouldn't use the two-column option. Now, if you want a final version, then, replace preprint with final.